# Angular - ErrorHandler vs HttpInterceptor

Tags: angular, angular-http-interceptors, angular-errorhandler

I would like to ask if there is any reason for using ErrorHandler and also HttpInterceptor when I want to show a specific error to end user?
My question motivation is - I have a project with Angular on frontend and Spring boot for backend and I want to distinguish frontend and backend error by different pop window (different css). I can´t catch frontend error in Interceptor and I would like to know if it´s better to use combination of ErrorHandler (for frontend) and Interceptor (for backend) or just ErrorHandler for both. I read that using Interceptor is the best solution for error handling in many forums, that´s why I am asking. What do you think? I could not find any answer for this question (maybe the question is very stupid). Thank you